# Connection Reset (PHP WebSockets)

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, connection

I tried implementing both [PHP-WebSocket](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets) and [Wrench](https://github.com/nicokaiser/php-websocket). Both ended up having the same problem: I cannot connect to any of them. Both Chrome and Firefox say that the connection has been reset. I run my Wrench server using the command line (`php server.php`). The problem is very likely to be caused by the client, since I don't normally do Javascript. Also, what's weird is that no exception is thrown within Javascript, there is just an error in the browsers console.

IMPORTANT EDIT:

WEBSOCKET_HOST is set to "localhost", WEBSOCKET_PORT is set to "9000"
Also, the server is running on a VirtualBox Ubuntu Server which is using port forwarding, though I never had problems with that, ssh and http port forwards work just fine.

EDIT 2:

I am able to connect to the server via the command line tool wscat just fine.

server.php

```
require_once(__DIR__."/../../composer/vendor/autoload.php");

use Wrench\Application\Application;
use Wrench\Application\NamedApplication;
use Wrench\Application\EchoApplication;

$server = new \Wrench\BasicServer('ws://' . WEBSOCKET_HOST .  ':' . WEBSOCKET_PORT, array(
    'allowed_origins' => array(
        HTTP_HOST,
    )
));

$server->registerApplication("app", new EchoApplication());
$server->run();
```

client.js:

```
function $(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }

var socket;

window.onload = function()
{   
    var host = "ws://<?php echo WEBSOCKET_HOST . ":" . WEBSOCKET_PORT ?>/app";
    try
    {
        socket = new WebSocket(host);

        socket.onopen    = 
        function(msg)
        { 
            window.alert("Connection Opened!");
        };
        socket.onmessage = 
        function(msg)
        { 
            $("json").innerHTML = msg;
        };
        socket.onclose   = 
        function(msg)
        { 

        };
    }
    catch(ex)
    { 
        window.alert(ex.message);
        $("json").innerHTML = ex.message;
    }
}

setInterval(function()
{
    if(socket != null && socket.readyState == 1)
    {
        socket.send("test");
    }
}, 500);

window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
    socket.close();
}
```

Comment: The try/catch won't fire because if there is an error connecting it simply calls the `socket.onclose()` function. I would do a `console.log(msg)` inside of `socket.onclose()` to see if it can help you debug.

Comment: JSON.stringify(msg) returns "{"isTrusted":true}", which does not help me much. Can you make something out of this?

Comment: I narrowed it down to a problem with my port forwarding in virtualbox. Cannot make sense out of this though